# Create Standard Data File in Mifare Desfire EV3

Tags: mifare, desfire

What is the command format for the createStdDataFile (0xcd) for a Mifare Desfire EV3 ICC?

I have no problem creating a data file with an EV1 ICC but with the new EV3 ICC, I get an APDU response of 91 9E. According to https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12752.pdf, it supports the command but differences in the file options.

Comment: What does an APDU response of 91 9E mean?

Comment: The documentation you have linked doesn't say that the command format is different between EV1 and EV3, just more options for FileOption are supported. Why do you think that the problem you observe has to do with the command format?

Comment: 91 9e = "Value of the parameter invalid". https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/complete-list-of-apdu-responses

Comment: My code still works for EV1 cards but fails with EV3 for this specific command. Its doesn't say more, it says different. And when I look at the documentation for CreateSTDDataFile, I don't see FileOptions; but I do see Access Rights. I assume it means this and if the format of this changed then it makes sense that this error is generated.